# How can I limit to only one relationship between two nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:

[image: THe Graph]

Currently I am using this QUERY to add a relationship between two nodes:

```
MATCH (a:Service),(b:Service)
WHERE a.service_id = 'cs2322' and b.service_id = 'ab3232'
CREATE (a)-[r:DEPENDENT_ON]->(b)
RETURN type(r)
```

However I dont want to have more than one relationship between any two nodes, because I want to visualise my services and the dependency between them, so I cannot have a service being two times dependent on the other.

Is there any way I can limit this to force neo4j server to throw an error if I try to create a relationship between two nodes which already have a relationship per direction with one-another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way to throw an error if you create a duplicate relationship. But that would also be a pretty expensive way to enforce such a policy.

Instead, you can use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of `CREATE` to avoid creating duplicate relationships.

For example, this query will only create the `DEPENDENT_ON` relationship if it does not already exist; otherwise, it will just bind the existing relationship to `r`:

```
    MATCH (a:Service), (b:Service)
    WHERE a.service_id = 'cs2322' AND b.service_id = 'ab3232'
    MERGE (a)-[r:DEPENDENT_ON]->(b)
    RETURN TYPE(r)
```

Comment: What about the potential reverse connection `(b)-[r:DEPENDENT_ON]->(a)`, I'm not sure if the author wants to permit those as well.

Comment: @cybersam As antimirov mentioned, I also want to be able to have reverse connection, but not more than one connection per direction (like the one at the picture). Maybe I was not fully clear on my statement.

Comment: Easy. To create the reverse connection you just use the same `merge` keyword with the relationship in the reverse direction: `MERGE (a)<-[r:DEPENDENT_ON]-(b)`.
This works as long as you don't add (or change) relationship properties. MERGE in this context means 'use the existing relationship as long as it has the same type and properties as the one you would otherwise create'.

Comment: Yes, if you *really* need to have the same relationship type in **both** directions, you can use @ChristophP's suggestion. But if you *always* have the same relationship type in both directions, that is a sign that you should actually just have a *single* relationship that is treated non-directionally! When you need to lookup the relationship, just use a non-directional pattern (like `(a)-[:FOO]-(b)`). `MERGE` also supports a non-directional pattern and will make sure there is a single relationship (direction does not matter).

Comment: @cybersam When I try to add attributes to the r:DEPENDENT_ON relationship, the MERGE does not limit the number of relationships, so I am again getting multiple one-way relationships between two nodes, is there any way I can stop that?

Comment: If you specify a `MERGE` pattern that includes the attributes (like `MERGE (a)-[r:DEPENDENT_ON {x:1, y:2}]->(b)`) then that should not create dupllicate relationships (with the same `x` and `y` values) between a given `a`/`b` pair. You may need to create a new question if you continue to have issues.